# Влияние кэш-памяти на производительность

Tags: производительность

Доброго времени суток.

Так ли важен рядовому пользователю размер кэш-памяти, то есть заметит ли он разницу 8 или 16, 16 - 32... Мое мнение - не особо, а вы как думаете?

Comment: @rojaster Мы изменили характер и направленность Вашего вопроса, чтобы он в большей мере соответствовал формату форума.

Comment: Немного сузьте вопрос - кеш чего имеется ввиду: операций с дисковой системой, процессорных комманд, сетевых операций..? Перечислять можно долго.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот кеш, как правило, хранит не только файлы, а некоторые другие элементы. Например, таблицу файловой системы для быстрого поиска сектора запрашиваемого файла, возможно, индексация присутствует.

Поэтому он важен, если у пользователя очень много файлов и много операций над ними производится. Т.е. при такой ситуации разница будет заметна. В остальных случаях - вряд ли.

Comment: Я соглашусь, но ведь все все равно определит размер: в смысле того, что он хранит - большие ли файлы или маленькие. Много маленьких файлов не есть гуд.

Answer (score 0):

Много маленьких файлов создаёт проблему памяти. Дефрагментатор оперативной памяти - MMSoft RAM Manager.

Comment: А за что его забанили?

Comment: @alvin Доступ к учетной записи участника Dimamur отключен за неоднократные ответы, не имеющие никакого смысла. Ответы участника (за исключением этого) удалены.